# python3: fileno() throwing I/O operation on closed file error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a background application where stdin, stdout and stderr would be re-directed from/to files. My code is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os

# Custom I/O files
myStdin = './stdin'
myStdout = './stdout'
myStderr = './stderr'

# Create empty files to be used by child to redirect I/O
open(myStdin, 'a').close()
open(myStdout, 'a').close()
open(myStderr, 'a').close()

# Close standard file descriptors before spawnning child
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stderr.flush()
sys.stdin.close()
sys.stdout.close()
#sys.stderr.close()

# spawn child and parent exits gracefully
p = os.fork()
if p:
    sys.exit(0)

# open files to redirect I/O (Non-buffered)
si = open(myStdin, 'r')
so = open(myStdout, 'ab+', 0)
se = open(myStderr, 'ab+', 0)

print(si.fileno())

# Duplicate the file descriptors
os.dup2(si.fileno(), 0)
os.dup2(so.fileno(), 1)
#os.dup2(se.fileno(), 2)

# Update the standard file objects with custom once
sys.stdin = si
sys.stdout = so
#sys.stderr = se
```

But, I am getting the error as below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(si.fileno())
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

What is going wrong, why is an open file prompted as closed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already closed the standard output with:

```
sys.stdout.close()
```

so the next time your try to `print` *anything* (to the standard output by default), you would get the `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` exception. So no, it does not have anything to do with accessing the `fileno()` method of `si`.

Answer (score 1):

Python file objects are not file descriptors. When you close a file object, it stays closed, regardless of whether the file descriptor it wrapped is reused.

Your `dup2` calls reuse the file descriptors originally assigned to stdin and stdout, but to get the file objects working, you need to either not call `close` on the original stdin/stdout file objects or replace them with new file objects. (Skipping the `close` calls is fine because `dup2` will silently close open file descriptors it copies over, without closing the file objects.)